# Could the radar on a passenger plane be used as a makeshift AWACS?

Tags: airliner, radar, radome

I'm aware that an airliner doesn't have a way to transmit data over datalink, but could an airliner at least tell other aircraft what they see on radar? Is an airliners radar powerful enough?

---

[image]

(Source : [Link](https://www.quora.com/Do-airliners-have-radar-If-so-of-what-sort))

Comment: Many aircraft do have a ‘datalink’ of some kind, but looking at the radar screen and describing by radio what the pilot sees is quite common.  The type of radar used on AWACS is far higher spec than that found on an airliner though, so it really depends on what ranges and level of detail is needed in any particular scenario.

Comment: @Frog Yeah I was thinking if a friendly airliner went close to a combat zone, it could relay target locations to friendly fighter jets.

Comment: I don’t know for certain but I’d be confident that fighters have at least as well-suited radars, and would be more willing to fly in/near a combat zone

Comment: @Frog haha definitely, but I was just curious if it was possible.

Comment: That's a weather radar. Used to detect weather, not aircraft.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, a weather radar is not able to detect small targets. Clouds are large volume objects, not comparable in size with an aircraft. It is very unlikely a weather radar could detect another aircraft, even at a distance of 2 NM.

(Let's put aside an AWACS is a command center and a tactical communication hub coupled with a multimode radar.)

[image]

[Source](http://aea.net/avionicsnews/anarchives/apr11_airborneradar.pdf).

**Radar cross section vs. beam size**

A weather radar scans the sky with a large beam, 4° to 10°. A cloud can intercept the totality of the beam energy. In contrary, an aircraft can only intercept a tiny fraction of this energy. This quantity when back-scattered is likely below the noise level of the radar receiver.

Radar frequency and beam size are selected in relation with the resonant frequency and the size of the target equivalent dipole. Weather radars are designed for water resonance and large packets of water droplets. They are not designed for targets of small [radar cross section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_cross_section) (RCS), e.g. a fighter with a RCS of 5m$^2$.

This is the main obstacle for aircraft detection, but there are also other points to be considered.

**Range and resolution**

If we take the [E-3](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_E-3_Sentry), the main radar has a 9m rotating passive antenna array working either in [C band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_band_(IEEE)) (around 5 GHz) or [S band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_band) (3 GHz), which are relatively low frequencies, selected because they allow more powerful transmitters and the signal is not significantly attenuated by the atmosphere. This is required to detect targets at more than 200 NM, which can be stratospheric missiles, low-flying aircraft and ships. The higher power requires a large antenna, this size in turn improves the angular resolution, even more in C band.

Weather radars work in S band, but with their small antenna, and their limited power, they don't have the previous advantages.

**Angular coverage**

The horizontal scan of a weather radar is about 120°, 1/3 of an AWACS. In the vertical direction, a weather radar has a very small aperture, limiting detection in a small vertical range and certainly not ballistic missiles or aircraft at the forefront of the ground surface.

**Doppler detection**

Clouds appear moving at the velocity of the aircraft. Most weather radars take advantage of this property, and use a Doppler shift measurement to detect clouds and rainfall.

A target moving parallel to the plane, would have a null Doppler shift and would be rejected by the radar processing unit. This could be used by the target to escape detection.

Answer (score 3):

The pilot can tell other aircraft what he sees on the radar. However, the weather radar is only really designed to detect dangerous weather.

There are multiple functions an airliner's weather radar lacks for Airborne Warning (AEW) use:

1. No ability to identify and IFF-interrogate other aircraft.
2. No tracking mode on the radar. Military radars first scan for targets, then switch to tracking them. (Advanced radars can also track while scanning).
3. Less ability to ignore weather due to a wider aperture.

We're talking AW, the first two letter of AWACS. AEW&C aircraft also carry staff with workstations to control and manage traffic. Datalinks are actually optional; they can transmit target coordinates in a way that allows a compatible radar to immediately track it without scanning. But voice communications are generally enough and more important.

In a practical scenario, a fighter radar will most likely be able to detect targets from a longer range than the airliner + its direct communications range (without relaying). One of the few exceptions I can think of is if an airliner is being escorted by a stealth fighter, and relays that information.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

Much, *much* more than a similar airframe is needed.  Consider that:

1. That giant Frisbee on the top has 360 coverage instead of a small cone out the front.
2. It's way more powerful.
3. There are all kinds of electronic equipment installed for signal processing, target interrogation and identification, plus encrypted voice and data communication, most of it classified as Secret or Top Secret.
4. There is an entire crew trained in the use of the equipment listed in #3, not just a couple pilots keying the mic and saying "*hey, I got something out there...*"

The AWACS is a fully engineered and integrated military mission system that can't be replaced by a simple weather radar in the nose cone and a VHF com radio.